# Azure DevOps pipeline running slowly

Tags: azure-devops

I have yaml pipeline in Azure Devops. Simple tasks such as building a project and running unit tests are taking 10 times longer today than they were. I'm in Europe and I can see that the Artifacts service is degraded. Would this explain the slow build and does anyone know a work-around such as a way to force the build agent to run in a different region?

https://status.dev.azure.com/

[image]

Comment: We have not found a work-around yet. We are facing the same problem since today and we are using a German server.
It took around 40 minutes to load the artifacts. Crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems is related to the following Azure DevOps Incidents:

- https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/233282345
- https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/233249026
- https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/233260207

Please try as the workaround mentioned in the Incident, adding the self-hosted agents to run your pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Now all regions have the problem with pipelines:

[image]